# List<? extends Object>#add(new MyClass()) doesn't compile

Tags: java, generics, extends

```or-java
MyClass e = new MyClass();

List<Object> ok = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<? extends Object> ko = new ArrayList<Object>();

ok.add(e);
ko.add(e); // doesn't compile
```

Why does it doesn't compile? `MyClass` is whatever a subclass of `Object`...

For information, I get the following message:

```
The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Object) in the type List<capture#1-of ? extends Object> is not applicable for the arguments (MyClass)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
List<? extends Object>
```

That means "it's a list of some type T which extends Object, but I don't care what T is".

So this would be valid:

```
List<? extends Object> ko = new ArrayList<Banana>();
```

... but you wouldn't want:

```
ko.add(e);
```

to compile at that point, would you? Because a `MyClass` isn't a `Banana`.

See the [Java generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#Wildcard%20Bounds) for *much* more information.

Comment: Even if MyClass were a Banana it would not compile.

Comment: @JonSkeet But I used `new ArrayList<Object>();`, not `new ArrayList<Banana>();`, and while `MyClass` isn't a `Banana`, it does is an `Object` though... So I still do not understand in fact `:'(`

Comment: @sp00m: That's the part on the right hand side of the assignment though. That's irrelevant to the *type of the variable* - and that's all that's important when you call `ko.add(e)`. That's like writing `Object x = "foo"; System.out.println(x.length());` and expecting it to work just because *you* know that `x` refers to a string...

Answer (score 1):

Josh Block, in *Effective Java*, teaches us **PECS**: Producer = `extends`, Consumer = `super`.

Since you are using `ko` as a *consumer* (you add an object to it) you should declare is as:

```
List<? super Object> ko = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Perhaps a better illustration of the concept would be:

```
List<? super MyClass> ko = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

You may think of it in the same way that you can only assign a MyClass object to a variable whose type is MyClass, or any super type -- you can only add a MyClass object to a List whose type is MyClass, or any super type.

Going back to your example, `List<? extends Object> ko` can't be the right type declaration because it would also accept this:

```
List<? extends Object> ko = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And you see here that, based on the generic type of `ko`, the compiler cannot be sure that the *actual* List accepts instances of MyClass.